# Why is Express not working at all?

Tags: node.js, express

I have been following the steps on [this](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/)  I got as far as

> npm install -g express-generator

but then nothing happens when I try to create an express project.  I go to the directory I want it to be in and type

> express nodetest1

and nothing happens.  It just returns to the next line.  It seems like everything installed correctly.

Edit: My link was to the wrong tutorial.  This is the right one now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try starting the server? The `express-generator` only *generates* the project.

Change to the directory of the created project and do `npm install` followed by `npm start` to start the server.

Comment: I don't think I even have a nodejs project started. The tutorial doesn't say to do that, but shouldn't I have to? I am confused and unfamiliar with all of this.

Comment: You said you ran the `express` command and that it created the project correctly, no?

Comment: No, I said nothing at all happens.  It just returns down a line.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was caused by nodejs, not Express.  When I installed the latest version usinv nvm instead of apt-get, express started working.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is

```
npm install -g express
```

There is a generator included in the main package.

So then you can use

```
express nodetest1
```

and everything works!

Comment: In Express 4, the generator is in a separate module: `express-generator`.

Comment: True, but the tutorial he's using is Express 3.

Comment: The tutorial is outdated :-)

Comment: Do you know of another tutorial that covers nodejs, express, and mongodb?  This has exactly all of the things I wanted to learn, but it simply does not work.

Comment: I installed express-generator seperately as well, and it doesn't generate anything.

Comment: Just for the record, I'm running Express 4.2.0 and `express nodetest1` works fine.